Help with Integral involving Square-root of Hyperbolic functions (definite)
I'm trying to solve the following integral for a project that I'm doing
\begin{equation}
 I = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{\sinh^2 x}-\left(b - \frac{c}{\tanh x} \right)^2} \, dx
\end{equation}
where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are the zeroes of the function in the square root $\frac{a^2}{\sinh^2 x}-\left(b - \frac{c}{\tanh x} \right)^2$. Furthermore, I assume that $b > c > a > 0$.
My attempt at solving this involved using the variable change $z = e^{-2x}$ to transform the integral into the square root of a quadratic polynomial coupled with factors $\frac{1}{z(1-z)}$. I then referred to the tables of integrals involving these types of functions but I didn't obtain the expected result, which should be $\pi \left(c - \sqrt{c^2 - a^2} \right)$.
UPDATE:
I will present here the formulas I obtained. Upon applying the variable change $z = e^{-2x}$ followed by partial fraction decomposition the integral was split into two integrals
\begin{equation}
I =  \int_{z_i}^{z_f} \frac{\sqrt{R_z}}{z-1}\,dz - \int_{z_i}^{z_f} \frac{\sqrt{R_z}}{z}\,dz   = I_1 - I_2
\end{equation}
where $R_z = -z^2(b+c)^2 + 2z(b^2-c^2+2a^2) - (b-c)^2$. The first integral $I_1$ can be brought into the same form as $I_2$ via another variable change $u = z-1$, which will transform the coefficients in the polynomial $R_z \to R_u = -u^2(b+c)^2 + 4 u(a^2 - b c - c^2) -4 (c^2-a^2) $. To solve integrals of the form $\int_{z_i}^{z_f} \frac{\sqrt{R_z}}{z}\,dz$, I referred to [1], namely the expression
\begin{equation}
I_1 = \left. \sqrt{R_u} \right|_{u_i}^{u_f} + \gamma \int_{u_i}^{u_f} \frac{du}{u \sqrt{R_u}} + \frac{\beta}{2} \int_{u_i}^{u_f} \frac{du}{\sqrt{R_u}}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ and $\beta$ arise from the description of the quadratic polynomial $R_u = \alpha u^2+ \beta u + \gamma$.
Then I used two more expressions from [1]
\begin{equation}
 \int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{R_u}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin \frac{2 \gamma + \beta u}{u \sqrt{-\Delta}}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{R_u}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\alpha}} \arcsin \frac{2 \alpha u + \beta}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}
\end{equation}
where $\Delta = 4 \alpha \gamma - \beta^2$. This ultimately lead me to the solution $I = \pi \left( c + \sqrt{c^2 - a^2}\right)$ and I can't find where the rogue $+$ sign comes from.
REFERENCES:
[1] I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik, Table of integrals, series, and products

Can you show a bit more detail of what form your transformed integral had and which formula you tried using from an integral table?

@DMcMor Sure, I updated the post with my attempt at the solution.

Should your original integral have $a^2$ instead of $a$?  I think you're off by a square, either there or when you found $R_{z}$, although I don't think that's the source of the error with the $+$ sign.

@DMcMor You're right, I forgot to insert it in when transcribing. As you said, that should not be the source of the error because I solved the integrals with the $a^2$.

I haven't worked out all the details, but I think the issue is that the formula $$ \int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{R_u}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin \frac{2 \gamma + \beta u}{u \sqrt{-\Delta}}$$ only holds for $u > 0$, and should  be negative when $u < 0$, as I think is generally the case when evaluating $I_1$ because of the shift when you changed variables.  If I have time to work out the details I  will update my answer, but I think that will fix your rogue $+$ sign.
Update:
If (so long as $\alpha < 0$ and $\Delta < 0$) we assume the formula
$$ \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{\alpha u^2+ \beta u + \gamma}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\alpha}} \arcsin \frac{2 \alpha u + \beta}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}$$ then we can derive the corrected formula.
$$\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{\alpha u^2+ \beta u + \gamma}} = \int\frac{\text{sgn}(u)}{\sqrt{\alpha u^4+ \beta u^3 + \gamma u^2}}\,du$$
Making the change of variables $z = 1/u$, $dz = -1/u^2\, du$ we get the integral
$$
\begin{align*}
-\int\frac{\text{sgn}(z)}{z^2\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{z^4} + \frac{\beta}{z^3} + \frac{\gamma}{z^2}}}\,dz &= -\int\frac{\text{sgn(z)}}{\sqrt{\gamma z^2 + \beta z + \alpha}} \,dz\\[5pt]
&=\text{sgn}(z)\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin \frac{2 \gamma z + \beta}{\sqrt{-\Delta}}
\end{align*}$$
Undoing the substitution gets us the formula we want:
$$\int \frac{du}{u \sqrt{\alpha u^2+ \beta u + \gamma}} = \text{sgn}(u)\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\gamma}} \arcsin \frac{2 \gamma + \beta u}{u\sqrt{-\Delta}}$$

Amazing, you hit the nail on the head. This fixes the rogue $+$ sign. Thank you very much! Update: Just to provide some more context, the initial variable $x$ is defined over $x \in (0,\infty)$ and so after the two variable changes we get $u \in (-1,0)$ which is now fixed with the sign function.
